# How to give range of values while using NDEigensystem for a 2D Schrödinger equation?

Tags: finite-element-method, eigenvalues

This program runs fine and I am able to get eigenvalues and eigenfunctions, however, I want to give a range of values for x and y. Can you suggest, how to edit my code for that?

```
 \[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];

V[x_, y_] = If[{x, y} \[Element] Region[\[ScriptCapitalR]], 0, \[Infinity]];

{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + V[x, y]*u[x, y],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] Region[\[ScriptCapitalR]], 10, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",\{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
```

Comment: On what should the range depend?

Comment: range should depend on x and y

Comment: Well, yes, but how?

Comment: I need to specify a range of the values for x and y where I am writing {x,y} are elements of Region[R], in the last line.

Comment: Still unclear what you want to do, show the code that does not work. Maybe it is possible to infer what you would like to do from that.

Comment: No the code works fine. I wanted to give a range of values to x and y without the need to define a region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];

V[x_, y_] = 
  If[{x, y} \[Element] Region[\[ScriptCapitalR]], 0, \[Infinity]];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + V[x, y]*u[x, y], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] Region[\[ScriptCapitalR]], 10];

Table[Plot3D[
  funs[[i]][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]], {i, 10}]
```

[image]